# Noise impact on X-band signal amplification

Tags: noise, radar, signal-power

I have a locally generated 10 GHz LO signal that should go into the LO port of a mixer. The LO signal strength is -1.7 dBm. The mixer has a required LO-drive of about 13 dBm. Before the LO signal hits the LO port of the mixer it needs to go through a 4-way splitter with a gain of -9.4 dB (insertion loss).

To achieve the 13 dBm LO-drive the LO signal needs to be amplified. An amp could be inserted before the splitter, after the splitter, or in both places. However, I would like to lower the number of components to avoid complexity and cost.

Can I just use one amp before the splitter? Low Noise Amps (LNA) usually have a noise figure (NF) below 2 dB, but not enough gain and P1dB is too low. I can find a medium power amp with 24 dB gain and 25 dBm P1dB but then the NF is above 8 dB.

Will an NF of 8 dB cause too much noise in the system or what it the best approach?

The RF signal into the mixer is 10 GHz.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: maybe a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Hilmar Good point. I will repost on the electronics stackexchange.